# How can I make a secondary webserver take over for the primary in the event of a hardware failure?

Tags: networking

I have a web server on my local area network.  How can I make it so that requests to that web server can be handled by a second (alternate/failover) system in the event that the first system fails?

I know this may be possible with a hardware router and active monitoring, but is it possible using software only (no special hardware)?  In other words, is there something I can configure in the operating systems of those two machines so that one system will act as an alternate for the other?  I'm not sure if they would need to appear to have the same IP (e.g.: client always accesses the same IP address like *10.0.0.123*) or if I'd need an mDNS name (like *myservice.local*) or what.

The client is just a web browser on a third device on the same local area network.  I'm running Ubunto 18.04 if that matters.  Currently I don't even have a dedicated DNS server or anything -- just a wi-fi router (and the two server pc's and the client browser device).

Is it possible, and if so, how?

Comment: You can set up a third server that would act as a reverse proxy to effectively create a load balancer. But in general, you cannot do what you wish to do with simply two servers: There should be three “servers” with the load balancer being what responds to `10.0.0.123` and then the load balancer then routes traffic behind the scenes to either one of the two “behind the scenes” real web servers. Apache can do this and so can Nginx. So you can even setup a Raspberry Pi with Apache or Nginx, set it up with two ethernet ports somehow and then… You have a load balancer!

Comment: Your proposed third-server load balancer is seemingly no more robust than a single server.  If the load balancer dies, the whole system goes down.  Who load-balances the load-balancer?  Is there no way to make the system more robust than a single server?  The idea is to remove the single-point-of-failure.

Comment: “Who load-balances the load-balancer?” Good question. But that is the most basic way to explain what a load balancer is. This is honestly how tons of websites work.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using software. The idea would be to have an IP address for the web server and then do monitoring to see if the server primary server is down, and if so coopt the IP address. I’d argue the IP address should be a secondary address.

http://www.linux-ha.org/ provides some software to do this if you dont want to role your own.

If you don’t need to access the server outside the network or have multiple IP addresses you could roll something using DNS (akin to dynamic DNS) instead of using IP takeover.

It’s probably not a great idea, but you may even be able to segment your network and use dynamic routing to route the IP address associated with the web server (treating at least one server as a router).

Answer (score 1):

If the web servers are serving static content, then the simplest answer is round-robin DNS. The client does a dns lookup and gets back two IP addresses (in random order) and will try them one after another.  You may get an error if one server is down, but refreshing will force the client to switch.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS